# How to sync up centos machines to same time/clock

Tags: centos, synchronization, clock

I have a vm (vm1) on which I installed everything I needed and am running a cronjob every 5 hours lets say.

Now using the snapshot of this vm instance I create many more virtual machines.

Now how do I ensure that my pre-scheduled "every 5 hours cron job" runs on all vms at the same time ?I want them to start at the same time but i am not sure how to synchronize the clock/time on all vms  any pointers? My vms are running  centos 7

Comment: can not ping the ntp servers from my vm ( i think i can not reach internet from my vms) any work arounds ?

Comment: Fix the network configuration of your VMs, or set up internal NTP servers that they can reach if the non-reachability is due to firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was 
1) fix network .. 
2) and since my vms were running centos .. i ended up using chrony

```
yum install chriny 
systemctl enable chronyd
```

check by

```
chronyc tracking  
chronyc sources
```

and make sure you can ping the sources